# Apache Beam bundling issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

My problem is the following, I want to aggregate some data that is stored on S3. As initial input to my pipeline I use a text file that contains the path of all the S3 files that should be aggregated.

```
 PCollection<String> readInputPipeline = p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()));
 readInputPipeline = readInputPipeline.apply(ParDo.of(new ReadFromS3Mapper()));
```

The input file has 346k lines. When I deploy this code to a Spark cluster reading from S3 looks like it happens only in 2 Spark Tasks even though many cores are available. Is there any way for me to increase the parallelism of this operation?

[image]

I am running this on EMR on Amazon with a master (m3.xlarge) and a core machine (R3.4xlarge) with the following options:

```
"spark-submit"
  "--driver-java-options='-Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/mnt/var/log/hadoop'",
  "--master", "yarn",
  "--executor-cores","16",
  "--executor-memory","6g"
```

PS: maybe the solution could be that I shouldn't do this kind of expensive IO operations in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Spark decides how to split up an input, here it's decided to go through the entire file in one go, because it so small.

I've done something similar in a [distcp application](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/cloud-integration/blob/master/spark-cloud-integration/src/main/scala/com/hortonworks/spark/cloud/applications/CloudCp.scala); this uses Spark's [ParallelCollectionRDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/ParallelCollectionRDD.scala) class to explicitly tell spark to split the listing up one-by-one.

That class should be enough for you to do something similar -you may have to read the initial text file in locally to a list, then pass the list to the `ParallelCollectionRDD` constructor

Comment: Thanks for the help but do you have any idea how to do the same with Beam?

Comment: no, but if you are using it with spark it may just line up. Try asking on the beam user mailing list at apache

Answer (score 0):

A bit late reply, but I looked into what Beam does in the 2.16.0 release.

You're getting 2 tasks after the first `TextIO.read()` -- I suspect that your initial list of files of 346k lines is being split into two partitions.  This behaviour is controlled by the [desiredBundleSize](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.16.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L226) inside TextIO, which is hard-coded to 64MB.

In Spark, your action `ReadFromS3Mapper` will be "fused" to the arriving records and you'll always stay at two partitions.

If you want to keep the same code, you can force a repartition between the two transformations:

```java
PCollection<String> allContents = p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()))
        .apply("Repartition", Reshuffle.viaRandomKey())
        .apply(ParDo.of(new ReadFromS3Mapper()));
```

**As an alternative**, there's quite a few interesting patterns available in the TextIO and [FileIO](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.16.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.java) utilities.  There's an example that matches yours [almost exactly](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.16.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L106) (implicitly including the `reshuffle`).